# Why does this javascript timer code work in Chrome debugger but not when run normally

Tags: javascript

The code below periodically updates a div element with new text.  If I set a breakpoint in the Chrome debugger and run in step mode the code updates the html as I expected.  But if run without any breakpoint set I see:

minutes = 0 seconds = 0

printed and then no change.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var g_t1 = null;
var g_t2 = null;

function StartTimer() {
   g_t1 = new Date();
}

function StopTimer() {
   g_t2 = new Date();
}

function CalcDuration() {
   StopTimer();

   var diff = g_t2.getTime() - g_t1.getTime();
   var place = document.getElementById("here");
   var minutes = Math.floor((diff / 1000) / 60);
   var seconds = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
   place.innerHTML = "minutes = " + minutes + " seconds = " + seconds;

   window.setTimeout(CalcDuration(), 100);
}

function Poller() {
   if(!g_t1)
     StartTimer();

   window.setTimeout(CalcDuration(), 100);
}

</script>
<body onload="Poller();">
<div id="here"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT.

For anyone interested both these variants work:

```
window.setTimeout(CalcDuration, 100);
```

or

```
window.setTimeout(function(){CalcDuration()}, 100);
```

Comment: `Poller` is only ever called one time... was this intentional?

Comment: Also the `onload` property should be `Poller` and not `Poller()`...

Comment: @natlee75  I think that's incorrect.  Changing onload="Poller;" doesn't work for me in Chrome.  onload surely expects a function to call?  However, window.setTimeout(func, .. is different.  I guess there if you pass just function anme it sees it like a function pointer, rather than call the function.  in Javascript terminology -  you are passing a reference to the function if no () specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your timer function call in an anonymous function, otherwise it executes immediately instead of within the scope of the timer.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){CalcDuration()}, 100);
```

Comment: Just about to say that...! :-) I would suggest instead just using `CalcDuration` instead... e.g. `window.setTimeout(CalcDuration, 100);`

Comment: You can also just take the parens off of `CalcDuration` in your `setTimeout`, but the above way is preferred.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that was as well, but learning the purpose of anonymous function is also useful for timers.

Comment: It also works if I use window.setTimeout(CalcDuration, 100); - ah just noticed comment above.  Hmmm I need to read up a bit more about js functions I think.  I guess CalcDuration() - says call function CalcDuration now whereas CalDuration - is passing reference to this function to SetTimeout.  Don't know.

Answer (score 0):

When setTimeout works in debug mode, but not in production, and you use the function reference syntax, e.g.

```
window.setTimeout(CalcDuration, 100);
```

then you should make sure that you are defining the function like this:

```
CalcDuraction = function() {
   ...
}
```

rather than

```
function CalcDuration() {
   ...
}
```